# Click Events inside fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, fragment, onclicklistener

I have a dashboard that is a *fragment*. Everytime I click a button, the *dashboard* is replaced by another *fragment*.

The **click listener** is implemented inside the dashboard fragment class. But I read somewhere that the better way to do it is to make the listeners inside the activity. Is it true? Why?

If yes, I can change it, i only have to copy the method in dashboard fragment to the activity, and make use of XML onClick feature.

Comment: It is better to place it into activity. You also can handle it inside fragment and then distribute it from fragment to activity, that is even better design I think. With is, that You can see the activity as "parent" so the parent listens to events of children and decides for himself, how to handle them. If a fragment says: "one  of my buttons told me to remove myself" the activity then can handle in an loose coupled way, instead of a tight coupled and encapsulated  way, the fragment would do. Imagine, Your fragment would be a control of a distributed library. How would You deliver this lib ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Until now I have the onClicklisteners inside the method OnActivityCreated. It works well, but I was asking my self if it is a good option

Comment: Read on this page on how to implement observer pattern via interfaces, which is more suitable for proper event handling in java.
http://www.vogella.com/

Comment: @icbytes, "it is better to place it into activity. You also can handle it inside fragment and then distribute it from fragment to activity, that is even better design I think. "  You say its "better" to place it in activity, then you go on to say it "is even better" to handle inside fragment, and distribute to activity (presumably via interface).  I think those two statements are contradictory..., can u clarify?

Comment: May seem as if they are contradictory. What I meant, is that from the framework design's point of view the fragment is the parent of the button. It should handle the button event in a encapsuled way, affecting only, what is on the fragment. And then pass the event to the fragments parent.

Comment: I agree...i just couldn't understand your statement that way.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly can't think of a reason for declaring an onClick listener for a fragment in the activity.

First, fragments are suppose to be modular.  Maybe you use it with this activity or that one.  Putting the onClicks in the activity hardcodes a relationship between the two.  Your activity is searching for the fragment, which isn't always there, and your fragment can't work except in that activity.

Second, where you declare your on click determines where it's implicit reference will be to.  If you declare it in the activity, it can call activity functions, but It has no idea which fragment it came from.  How does it reference fragment functions / data?  Sure there's elaborate workarounds but why?

On the other hand, if you put it in the fragment, it can call the fragment functions. and it has the same life-cycle as the fragment (being attached to a fragment view), so the implicit reference isn't going to create a memory leak (by itself anyways).  And if you want to call the activity, just use getActivity and cast it to your interface or subclass.